# How to set a default selected item with a listview/combo box uwp

Tags: c#, combobox, win-universal-app

I would like a ComboBox to have a default selected value, in this case it would be the first item in the viewmodel.

```
<ComboBox  Name="cat_choices" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Categories}" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Category">                            
            <TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind cat_name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

From the viewmodel:

```
private ObservableCollection<Category> categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get { return this.categories;  } }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 new property in your ViewModel:

```
private int _SelectedIndex = 0;

    public int SelectedIndex 
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIndex));
        }
    }

private Category _SelectedQuality = null;
    public Category SelectedQuality
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedQuality;
        }
        set
        {
            _SelectedCategory = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCategory ));
        }
    }
```

When you finish populate your Categories, set `SelectedCategory = Categories.First();`

in xaml, binding `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedItem` property of ComboBox to the newly created properties in ViewModel, set binding mode = two way.

Comment: I can't find the namespace for RaisePropertyChanged. My app links to a sqlite database.

Comment: I am using the same idea but with INotifyPropertyChanged. I am not sure about the xaml: SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"  ??

Comment: SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}" only.
RaisePropertyChanged is same ideal with your implemetation of INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Ok!! It works with SelectedIndex="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"> and without the SelectedItem property set. When the SelectedItem property is set similarly with x:Bind, I get a message saying I need a converter to bind a Category to a System.Object. It does not work with only SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}">.

Comment: SelectedItem of Combobox, listview, gridview is of type object. x:Bind is a compile time binding. So it will check for type match. Thus it will complain of data type if you use x:Bind instead Binding.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the `SelectedIndex` to `0` in the `Loaded` event in code behind of the ComboBox? Since you always want to set the selected item to the first item, this will be simple enough.

Or

If you want it to be implemented in XAML itself, use an `EventTrigger` for `Loaded` Event inside the ComboBox and use a `Setter` to set the property `SelectedIndex` to `0`.